# Remove elements after an item in a list, jQuery - Part 2

Tags: jquery, css

I have a code block like this:

```
<span class="main_container">
    <span id=".." class=".." position="1"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="2"...> </span>  
    <span id=".." class=".." position="3"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="4"...><img class="remove_it" scr="images/remove.png" /> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="5"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="6"...> </span>
</span>
```

Basically I want that once the `remove_it` image is clicked, the `span` element containing it (the image) be removed and all other `span elements` below it. In this case, elements at 4,5, and 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) functionality.

**HTML**

```
<p id="1">1</p>
<p id="2">2</p>
<p id="3">3</p>
<p id="4">4</p>
<p id="5">5</p>
<p id="6">
    6
    <span id="click">Click</span>
</p>
<p id="7">7</p>
<p id="8">8</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#click").on("click", function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.nextAll().remove();
    $parent.remove();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s56dS/).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.remove_it').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll('span').add(this.parentNode).remove();
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsTnY/1/).

Also, as an addenda, if you're using custom attributes you may as well prefix them with the `data-`, in order that, at least, they'll then be valid within an HTML5 doctype.

Edited the answer to correct `this` to `this.parentNode` as it should have been.

Comment: This doesn't remove the `4th` element, adding `addBack/andSelf` does the trick.

Comment: @undefined: yeah, I caught that as I was building the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wsTnY/), thanks! =)

Comment: This  removes the click element but doesn't remove the containing SPAN. Thanks though

Comment: @DavidThomas About the data-  I noticed that yesterday as I was working with position, thanks for the suggestion. I m not hardcore jQuery, but I m getting to love it more and more.

Answer (score -1):

use parent(), [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/), [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) ...

try this

```
$('.remove_it').click(function(e){
   $(this).parent().nextAll('span').addBack().remove();
});
```